# Get set of all existing values in a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Have a table with about 500,000 rows. One of the columns is a string field.

Is there a way to get the set of all existing values of that string in PostgreSQL without having to request each row out of the database and add the values to a set manually?

Example:

```
first_name      last_name
will            i.am            
will            smith
britney         spears
```

The set of all existing values for "first_name" would be `['will', 'britney']`.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT first_name FROM myTable;` and `SELECT DISTINCT last_name FROM myTable;`? Or I guess I'm missing something on the question here...

Comment: You want a set, right? Not an array or a concatenated string? The very fine manual has a chapter on [`SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) with all you need here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name FROM people;
```

or

```
SELECT first_name FROM people GROUP BY first_name;
```